# Kubernetes not able pull image from private registry having private domain pointed via /etc/hosts

Tags: kubernetes, coredns, microk8s

I am trying to deploy an image from my private registry that's hosted on my local network and pointed using my local machines /etc/hosts file.

I am getting the resolution error as below:

```
Failed to pull image "gitlab.example.com:5050/group/project:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to resolve image
```

My /etc/hosts file contains:

```
192.168.1.100 gitlab.example.com
```

Using docker the pull/push works perfectly fine as the resolution happens using /etc/hosts

I've tried editing corefile of coredns to make the resolution happen, but it isn't working.

Can someone point me in right direction over here.

Comment: what did you edit in Corefile?

Comment: before: forward . 8.8.8.8

after: proxy . 192.168.1.105:53


where 192.168.1.105 is my DHCP network ip

I tried other methods as well like using fallthrough for a specific domain, still didn't work.

Comment: Did you read this: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/ ?

Comment: Yes, I've created the image pull secret and associated the same with the deployment. Problem is not authentication, but the resolution of sub domain gitlab.example.com which is not there in public dns, but routed using /etc/hosts file.

Comment: Try `192.168.1.100 gitlab.example.com` (swap ip and domain in /etc/hosts).

Comment: Sorry my bad, I've corrected the question. IP and domain are as expected already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use [hostAliases](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/add-entries-to-pod-etc-hosts-with-host-aliases/)  and add a host entry to your pod. Kubernetes will not honor the `/etc/hosts` file from the hosts/nodes. Either the one in the pod or resolves through CoreDNS. For example:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: hostaliases-pod
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  hostAliases:
  - ip: "192.168.1.100" 
    hostnames:
    - "gitlab.example.com" 
  containers:
  - name: gitlab-hosts
    image: myimage
    command:
    - mygitlabjob
    args:
    - "arg1"
```

Update:

I think see the problem here. microk8s on Ubuntu runs in a `snap`. That means it's [confined/sandboxed](https://snapcraft.io/docs/snap-confinement) in a container of its own. This also means that it probably doesn't care about your machine's `/etc/hosts` file. Unfortunately, snap's file systems are mounted as read-only for security reasons and to prevent tampering.

```sh
○ → pwd
/snap/microk8s/current
○ → sudo touch hosts
touch: cannot touch 'hosts': Read-only file system
```

If you'd like to use a private registry this way, some recommendations:

- Ask your system admin to add that entry into your local DNS server, or add it if you are the system admin.
- Use an alternative small K8s distro that uses Docker.

  - [KinD](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/quick-start/)
  - [minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/)
- Build your own microk8s snap with a modified `/etc/hosts` file (hard)

Comment: I've added it in deployment.spec.template.spec since this template would be used for deploying pods. This didn't work.

Comment: I guess these aliases only work within the container once it's deployed in the pod and not before that when the image needs to be pulled from the private registry having custom hostname.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, this will not work for pulling images. Are you using microk8s on a Mac? What's your setup?

Comment: It's microk8s on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks Rico! Shall try using minikube and post an update.

Comment: Update: I tried with k3s and the image pull worked. Thanks.